# Windows GPO "Allow Remote Shell Access", where to set 'False' once you enable it?

Tags: windows, group-policy, shell, remote

OS : Windows 7 64 bit

Under Local Group Policy Editor > Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Remote Shell >

there is a policy setting

"Allow Remote Shell Access", which is set to 'Not Configured' by default.

Part of the description states "If you enable this policy setting and set it to False, new remote shell connections will be rejected by the server." While one can enable this setting, there is no provision to set it to 'False' https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2LK8.jpg within the GUI

My intent is not to "Allow Remote Shell Access". How can this be achieved?

Comment: Yay, Group Policy logic :-) What were they smoking when they designed this. Someone should tell them to enable a setting you change the option to *Enabled* and not call the option *Disable xxx* and disable it!